# Error Message: The server tag is not well formed

Tags: c#

When I use the below code, this error is shown:

> The server tag is not well formed

Markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="AddProduct" runat="server" 
            style="color:white" Text= "Add Product"   
            onclick="AddProduct_Click" 
            BackColor="Black" 
            TextBox1.text="string.Empty" TextBox2.text="string.Empty" 
            TextBox3.text="string.Empty" TextBox4.text="string.Empty" />
```

Comment: what all these things TextBox1.text = "string.Empty" TextBox2.text= "string.Empty " TextBox3.text= "string.Empty" TextBox4.text= "string.Empty" ???

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign another textbox's text in one button.

```
<asp:Button ID = "AddProduct" runat = "server" style ="color:white" Text= "Add Product"   
    onclick= "AddProduct_Click" BackColor = "Black" 
    TextBox1.text = "string.Empty" />
```

if you want to change those on click of the button then create click event handler in the back end and then set those properties their. Your code has registered that handler as named `AddProduct_Click`.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting textbox texts inside the AddProduct_Click event handler in the code behind file.
For instance,

```
TextBox1.Text="";
TextBox2.Text="";
TextBox3.Text="";
TextBox4.Text="";
```

You need not add these expression in the button tag. Make sure that runat="server" has been given in the button tag.

Hope this will resolve your problem.